# Contradiction in Lagragian multiplier equations from constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to solve a Lagrangian multiplier equation however the partial derivatives seem to result in a contradiction (the last 4 equations). Any help is much appreciated! thank you in advance.

To maximize:

U(x,y,z) = 1000/(1+e^(-0.01(x-500) ) )+250lg(y)-100 sin²⁡(0.01z)+1.2z

Subjected to

5x + 30y + 50z ≤ 1500

5x ≤ 600

30y ≤ 600

50z ≤ 600

The Lagrange function should result in:

U(x,y,z,λ_1,λ_2,λ_3,λ_4 ) = 1000/(1+e^(-0.01(x-500) ) )+250lg(y)-100 sin^2⁡(0.01z)+1.2z+λ_1 (5x+30y+50z-1500)+λ_2 (5x-600)+λ_3 (30y-600)+λ_4 (50z-600)

∂U/∂x = (10e^(-0.01(x-500)))/((1+e^(-0.01(x-500) ) )^2 )+5λ_1+5λ_2 = 0

∂U/∂y = 250/(yln(10))+30λ_1+30λ_3 = 0

∂U/∂z = 1.2-sin⁡(0.02z)+ 〖50λ〗_1+〖50λ〗_4 = 0

∂f/(∂λ_1 ) = 5x + 30y + 50z - 1500 = 0         (12)

∂f/(∂λ_2 ) = 5x - 600 = 0            (13)

∂f/(∂λ_3 ) = 30y - 600 = 0          (14)

∂f/(∂λ_4 ) = 50z - 600 = 0          (15)

Comment: Without looking very closely at the correctness of what you did, just wondering: why do you expect for a solution to exist if you have $3$ variables, and $4$ constraints? In general, if you're optimizing over a bounded domain then the strategy is to check for local minima/maxima in the interior, and then optimize individually over each piece of the boundary. Then take the minimum/maximum of all results.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: It is really hard to read the above, please format is using MathJax.